# How to run executable from shell in ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I have this folder which contains a program i can launch by double clicking on its executable, but it doesn't run from the console.

some info:

> ➜  knime_3.5.3 file knime
>
> knime: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64,
>   version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter
>   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, with debug_info, not
>   stripped
>
> ➜  knime_3.5.3 ls -l knime
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 rob rob 80393 apr  4 22:18 knime

Stuff i've already already:

- right click on it, go to permission, check the "Allow execution as program"

> ```
> ➜  knime_3.5.3 knime
> zsh: permission denied: knime
>
> ➜  knime_3.5.3 sudo knime
> [sudo] password for rob: 
> sudo: knime: command not found
> ```

Comment: Is that directory in your `PATH`?

Comment: Have you tried to run `./knime`?

Comment: @muru no it's not, i'm a dumbass -,-

Comment: @Melebius  thanks, using the path it works, i was sure it was on my path